# Fault tolerant RAID6 / RAID10 design for home server - not performance critical

Tags: linux, mdadm, raid-10, home-server

I want to balance disk space against fault tolerance. I would like fault tolerance to be able to handle multiple disk failures (as I may not be able to afford replacements disks or have the time for weeks possibly)

The main purpose of the home Linux server shall be a place to backup other machines too, store/share large amounts of data. So the data will be re-creatable most of the time. Storage of media (ie backup of my DVD's, Cd's etc)

I **had** a RAID10 array of 6 x 1.5TB but due to operator incompetence and laziness, I now have 6 empty disks :-) and a clean start.

One of the disks is definitely failing (over 55 error from smartctl and short and long test errors) so it will be sent away for warranty replacement - but I would still like to include it in the final array. Lets call the bad disk /dev/sdc

Machine has 6 sata ports and 2 IDE (with 2 CD drives). Dual Quad core Xeon, 16Gb RAM. And really 1 user most of the time.

*[NB I may be able to remove a CD drive and add a 7th IDE disk just for the OS only to separate data/OS] Otherwise plan is to save 100GB partition and put the OS there (maybe mirror between disks)*

**Option A)**
RAID 6 sd[abdef], sdc as hot-spare (but gets sent for replacement soon) raid-devices=5 spare=1

**Option B)**
RAID 6 sd[abdef], sdc as missing (but gets sent for replacement soon)
raid-devices=6 spare=0

**Option C)** RAID 10 sd[abdef], sdc as hot-spare (but gets sent for replacement soon) raid-devices=5 spare=1

**Option D)** RAID 10 sd[abdef], sdc as missing (but gets sent for replacement soon) raid-devices=6 spare=0

Option A is seeming to be the best at the moment because I'll get 4.5TB of space and room for 3 disk failures if I calculate it correctly.

This will all be done with mdadm soft raid.

Which do you recommend or are there better possibilities layouts that I could use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raid10 may not be able to handle two disks failing, so raid6 would be more reliable.  It also gives more storage capacity.  Option A only can handle the third failure if it happens *after* the rebuild onto the hot spare completes, but you only get 50% of the total space.

The odds of having 3 out of 6 disks fail are *very* slim, so I would be inclined to think that the loss of space ( and throughput ) is not worth having a hot spare.  What you could do as a compromise is run without a hot spare, and in the event that you have a failure, and know you can not replace it for some time, and are worried that you might have two more failures, you could then reshape the array to a 5 disk raid6 and be back to being able to handle two more failures.

This requires that you use a filesystem that you can shrink since reshaping the array will reduce its capacity.

Comment: Good point about having 3 failed disks.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you check out Robin Harris (StorageMojo)'s blog *[Dear StorageMojo: cheap home bulk storage?](http://storagemojo.com/2011/08/08/dear-storagemojo-cheap-home-bulk-storage/)*. Robin, who writes about the data storage industry, thinks he should change his storage server "from RAID 5 to multiple RAID 0 stripes for speed and capacity." But read the 50 comments for other opinions.

- ZFS to administer the file system and drives. But, "stay AWAY!! from ZFS unless you are a sysadmin type or SUN customer. I’m on zfs-discuss and the sheer number of problems people run into for simple stuff is mind-boggling", says another commenter
- [Drobo](http://www.drobo.com/), but "too expensive per gigabyte"
- "mini-atx PC (the size of a breadbox) running either [openfiler](http://www.openfiler.com) or [freenas](http://www.freenas.org)"
- Solaris 11 Express
- "RAID 0 is bad news and when it fails you *will* have major corruption issues."
- '“The folks asking this question aren’t full time sysadmins..” Soon as I read this I thought “Get a NAS”.', e.g. 'QNAP 659 Pro+ with 6x 2 TB drives in a RAID-6 configuration.'
- "what is wrong with just high grade SATA spindles, an a mirror copy, same spec? Things like WE4 do not even power up unless needed.... And suddenly, for

I don't claim this picks one of the options you put forward. But it is food for thought.

Me, I chose a NAS, with 2x1 TB drives in Raid-1 (mirrored). Every now again I rotate one of the drives to off-site storage and plug the previous off-site drive into the NAS.

Comment: Thanks but I already have all the hardware - for a few years now - plus I run Virtual Machine and large compiles on the server too. So its making best use of what I have